# Ksh script warnings

Tags: scripting, ksh

While running my script, I got the following message (it's not an error strictly speaking, because the execution go ahead after) :

```
myScript -s test -u test2
pk_copylogs[2]: hist: :: not found
```

However, do you know why does this message appear ?

Comment: Run it with `ksh -x myScript -s test -u test2 2>&1 | sed -n l > some-file` and look in `some-file` for what is being done just before the error.

Comment: Also, when asking for help about a script's error, ALWAYS include the relevant lines from the script.

Comment: I agree, but thus I don't know what is this error about, I don't know what goes wrong with my script, and which lines are prolematic.

Comment: Show us the script!

Comment: pk_copylogs looks like another script, but might even be a shell function - correct?

Comment: Please include the version of ksh, and/or your unix version. If you're on AIX, you may need to run the script under `ksh93`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hist` command is a korn shell (ksh93) builtin, and is not available in bash.

Your script(s) appears to be running under bash, not ksh.

```
ksh$ command -V hist
hist is a shell builtin   

bash$ command -V hist
bash: command: hist: not found
```

Try the following:

```
$ ksh myScript -s test -u test2
```

or:

```
$ SHELL=ksh ksh myScript -s test -u test2
```

However, `hist` is a command that's typically only used in interactive mode,
and I would not expect it in a script.  It is rarely invoked directly, and
more often as one of the following aliases:

```
$ alias | grep hist
fc=hist
history='hist -l'
r='hist -s'
```

Look for any of `fc`, `history`, `r`.

Comment: It works. Actually, it was the line author : ... which wasn't commented. 
Thank you.

Comment: `fc` used to be the original command history editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the second line of the `fc_copylogs` script, this is the one that trigger the error message.

Here is one way to reproduce exactly the same message you got:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cat > pk_copylogs <<%
#!/bin/ksh
fc $1
%
$ chmod +x /tmp/pk_copylogs
$ PATH=$PATH:/tmp pk_copylogs ::
pk_copylogs[2]: hist: :: not found
```

Of course, it might not be exactly the same situation in your case but it is certainly very close.

The second line of pk_copylogs might simply contain this line

```
hist ::
```

which would produce the very same error message, or anything that would expand to it.

If you have no idea about where to look, you can run this command to locate the faulty script:

```
find / -name pk_copylogs -print
```

and then have a look to its first lines with

```
head /path/to/pk_copylogs
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `myScript` code, there is a call to another external script called `pk_copylogs`. On the second line of the pk_copylogs, there is an assumption that you have a command called `hist` accessible from anywhere, i.e., in one of the directories included in your `$PATH` variable.

The most likely cause of this problem is, in most shells I have worked with which I didn't have to configure my shortcuts, but someone prior to me did, the command `hist` is aliased to command `history` for the convenience purposes. But when you launch a shell script, that alias goes out the window. Of course your case might be totally different but without seeing the actual code of these two scripts you referenced, i.e., myScript and pk_copylogs, it is very hard to make any assertions